# Sensors used in Compact elctronic vehicles

Tags: datasheet, measurement, automotive, potentiometer, accelerometer

I am doing a group report on Compact electric vehicle and was asked to determine suitable sensors to measure the longitudinal speed and throttle pedal position of the vehicle. We did some research and found this thus far:

•   Sensors for longitudinal speed:

1. Incremental rotary encoder (*Sendix* 5020 with hollow shaft)
2. Hall effect-based DSM1-10 Speed Sensor

•   Sensors for throttle pedal position:

1. TLE4990 *Infenion's* linear hall sensors
2. TLE4997 *Infineon’s* linear Hall sensors

We've read up about each sensors but we're just wondering if perhaps (for the sensors of the longitudinal speed and throttle pedal)there might be other sensors which works better which we have little to no knowledge of?

We need two of each sensors and its technical name, hence if anyone of mastery in this area can assist us, it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I would think that you would just use one position sensor for pedal position and calculate the pedal movement speed from that via differentiation.

Comment: For pedal position, have you looked at potentiometers and LVDTs ? What are specifications for each sensor (including operating environmental conditions and required reliability) ? Start from that to see if the selected sensors are adequate.

Comment: why is Compact spelled with capital C?

Comment: Marketting guys like to inflate the little brands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that for ECU control of wheel speed around corners and ABS braking that independent wheel speed sensors (WSS) are popular now.

There is an **AK automotive standard** for **WSS chips** that supports a variety of permanent magnets in wheels is a combination of analog index current-pulses like 96 pulses/rev such as the Allegro ARS19200 and **newer ones with a biphase data word between Index pulses** to support this from *[Infineon TLE4394C IC](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLE4943C-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4626c1f3dc3016c484bd04016f6)*  and possibly NXP KMI17/4.

But none of these are specific to any size car.  Yet the TLE4394C is pretty compact already.
[image]

I also made a simulation of the signals if interested.

Comment: Thank you @Tony Stewart EE75 , we actually already have the datasheet you have attached in your answer as our reference in the report. I am going to consult the rest of my teammates with your findings. I truly appreciate your kind advice and thanks again.

Comment: Would like my simulation?